# Symfony2 bootstrap popover doesn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I have a problem with a very simple popover. so I decide to test with bootstrap page example and there is no problem without symfony but with symfony and twig the button doesn't make anything.

Before that I tested with jQuery mobile and the popover was a full page instead of a pop-up.

I don't know where is the problem thanks in advance for your help :).

The source code in Firefox seems OK and the code without symfony, it's the same when I look in the browser code source :x.

**from scratch without SF**:

```
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>popover</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">

     <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
     <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>

//here all it's ok 
    <script>
     $(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**and whith SF**:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Sebastien Caumes</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sebastiencaumes/web/bundles/scsebastiencaumes/css/bootstrap.min.css">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sebastiencaumes/web/bundles/scsebastiencaumes/css/global.css">



      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/sebastiencaumes/web/favicon.ico" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 header">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i>
            </button>


            HEADER
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                DESCRIPTIF COMPETENCES ETC
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="test-box">projet1
                  <a href="/sebastiencaumes/web/app_dev.php/work/3">clic</a>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>


                  <script>
                    $(function() {
                      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
                    })
                  </script>
                </div>
                <div class="test-box">projet2</div>
                <div class="test-box">projet3</div>
                <div class="test-box">projet4</div>
                <div class="test-box">projet5</div>
                <div class="test-box">projet6</div>
                <div class="test-box">projet7</div>
                <div class="test-box">projet8</div>
                <div class="test-box">projet9</div>
                <div class="test-box">projet10</div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 footer">
            FOOTER
            <div class="pull-right">

              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-blackboard"></i>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-blackboard"></i>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-blackboard"></i>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script src="/sebastiencaumes/web/bundles/scsebastiencaumes/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/sebastiencaumes/web/bundles/scsebastiencaumes/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/sebastiencaumes/web/bundles/scsebastiencaumes/js/global.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**and in SF page whith jquery function**:

```
    {% extends'SCSebastienCaumesBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

    {% block portfolio %}
        <div class="test-box">projet1
        <a href="{{ path('sc_sebastien_caumes_work_detail', {id : 3}) }}">clic</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing
             content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>


            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
                })
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="test-box">projet2</div>
        <div class="test-box">projet3</div>
        <div class="test-box">projet4</div>
        <div class="test-box">projet5</div>
        <div class="test-box">projet6</div>
        <div class="test-box">projet7</div>
        <div class="test-box">projet8</div>
        <div class="test-box">projet9</div>
        <div class="test-box">projet10</div>
    {% endblock %}
```

I think its a very simple problem but I don't see it.

Comment: Please edit your examples, they appear to be jumbled together

Answer (score 0):

Finally all is ok. after clear the cache manualy and erase the .js from server and web local directory an re-run a assets:install... :)